# How to generate multivariate normal distribution in J

Tags: random, normal-distribution, j, multivariate-testing

How do I generate a multivariate distribution in J given the mean value vector and the covariance matrix?

For example, in Python,
`np.random.multivariate_normal([0,0],[[1,.75],[.75,1]],1000)`
generates a multivariate distribution with `[0,0]` as mean value vector and `[[1,.75],[.75,1]]` as the variance-covariance matrix?
Thanks

Comment: What have you tried? How far have you gotten?

Answer (score 2):

Wikipedia describes a [standard method for creating multivariate normal distributions](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Multivariate_normal_distribution#/Drawing_values_from_the_distribution):

```
   Mu=: 0 0                   NB. vector of means
   ]Sigma=: 1 0.75 ,: 0.75 1  NB. covariance matrix
   1 0.75
0.75    1
```

We can get the Cholesky Decomposition of the covariance matrix using code from the `matfacto.ijs` script in the `math/misc` addon (or use the [LAPACK addon](http://code.jsoftware.com/wiki/Addons/math/lapack))

```
   load 'math/misc/matfacto'
   A=: choleski Sigma         NB. Cholesky decomp
```

Create 2 independent univariate normal variables using the [stats/distribs](http://code.jsoftware.com/wiki/Addons/stats/distribs) addon.

```
   load 'stats/distribs'
   z=: rnorm 2 1000           NB. 2 standard normal variables sampled 1000 times
```

Now generate the desired multivariate distributions:

```
   X=: Mu + A mp z
```

Now check that the distributions are as specified:

```
   load 'stats/base'
   mean"1 X
0.0264368 0.00887907    NB. mean close to 0 (Mu)
   stddev"1 X
0.987214 0.991614       NB. stddev close to 1 (sqrt of diagonal of Sigma)
   corr/ X
0.746917                NB. correlation close to 0.75 (off-diagonal of Sigma)
```

We can code this as a single verb:

```
multivar_norm=: dyad define
  'Mu Sigma'=. x
  A=. choleski Sigma
  z=. rnorm y ,~ #Sigma
  Mu + A mp z
)

   X=: (Mu;Sigma) multivar_norm 1000
   ((mean , stddev)"1 ; corr/) X
┌──────────────────┬────────┐
│0.0199138  1.01788│0.749184│
│ 0.035176 0.987191│        │
└──────────────────┴────────┘
```

Comment: That's very neat. I've thought about using Cholesky Decomposition, too. Thank you very much